# PhpStorm print the script of php instead of html page

Tags: php, html, sql, google-chrome, phpstorm

I'm developping a project of a generator of CV in HTML/PHP/CSS/SQL on a local server. When I use the chrome option to run a php file on PHPStorm, it prints the code between the two php tags and not the html page. It started today, before that all worked perfecty well.

```
  <html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Page d'inscription</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class = "carre_acceuil">
        <div class = "titre_acceuil">
            Inscription
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="inscrire.php">
            <div class = "formulaire_acceuil">
                <label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "prenom" placeholder="Prenom" required class="input_acceuil"><br><br>
                    <input type = "text" name = "nom" placeholder ="Nom" required class="input_acceuil"><br><br>
                    <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder ="Adresse email" required class="input_acceuil"><br><br>
                    <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder ="Mot de passe" required class="input_acceuil"><br><br>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" class="bouton">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the file "inscrire.php" is here:

```
 <?php
$nom = $_POST["nom"];
$nom = ucfirst(strtolower($nom));
$prenom = $_POST["prenom"];
$prenom = ucfirst(strtolower($prenom));
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = crypt($_POST["password"]);

//se connecter a la base de donee
$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ifd1_gestion_cv;charset=utf8", "root", "");

// Créer une requête INSERT INTO pour insérer un étudiant
$req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO comptes (nom, prenom, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");

// Exécuter la requête
$req->execute([ucfirst($nom), ucfirst($prenom), $email, $password]);

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Comment: you'll need to show some code if you're going to get help

Comment: any changes? local server change, php update or else ?

Comment: @Svetoslav I just pulled the last version but my friends have the same version, use phpmyadmin too, and phpstorm and it works for them

Comment: If you see the code of a php file instead of the expected output, it would be that your php isn't interpreted. I don't know what PhpStorm prints the script means. Are you using the Open in browser link in PhpStorm? If so, I never used that so I'm not sure but maybe it has something to do with the interpreter configured  in Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Cli interpreter.

Comment: @JulienB. i was just thinking the same, upon re-reading the question it's actually about settings within phpstorm, and not a code question at all.

Comment: @elios_cama - i also never use that option (just open your browser and hit refresh lol) but I'd recommend contacting phpstorm on twitter, they've always been really quick and helpful to respond when i've had issues/queries about phpstorm

Comment: @JulienB. i checked the interpreter and i have the one that worked before so it's not an interpreter issue, thanks anyway!

Comment: @jameson2012 . Thanks I'll try to contact them

Comment: Does the interpreter still exist? Can you find it if you look in that location on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

update, i desinstalled phpstorm and reinstalled it and now it works, thank you all!